# ora-30667 cannot drop not null constraint on a default on null column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Before all, I appreciate any help and am sorry about my English.

I'm a student and my teacher created a schema for me, so I could work with an Oracle database. It was working well, but today I deleted some tables and added others, and when I try to insert something in the new tables, it gives me an error:

> ora-30667 cannot drop not null constraint on a default on null column

I read some things about that error, and some say to purge the recycle bin, but it didn't work for me; it is still giving me that error.

Even a simple example gives me the error:

```
create table example(example_id number(10), example_name varchar(255));
insert into example(example_id, example_name) values(1, 'example');
```

Please help me, I have to do the work, but that error is not letting me do it.

Oracle Version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Edition:

I tried this, as a complete example:

```
create table tipo_funcionario(
id_tipo_funcionario number(10),
descricao varchar(255)
);

insert into tipo_funcionario(id_tipo_funcionario, descricao) values(1, 'gestor');
```

I execute and it says that:

> ```
> insert into tipo_funcionario(id_tipo_funcionario, descricao) values(1, 'gestor')
>
> Error report - 
>
> SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive sql level 1
>
>
> ORA-30667: cannot drop not null constraint on a default on null column
>
> 00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
>
> *Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
>            (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
>
> *Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
>            can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
> ```

Comment: I can't reproduce.  Which statement exactly is giving you the error?  I find it hard to believe that an `insert` statement would give the error you mention.

Comment: Agree with @sstan. Please copy and paste the commands you enter and the error you get.

Comment: For what it's worth, by googling this a little, it does seem like there may be some odd bug in Oracle 12c.  But other than purging the recycle bin, I don't see any other useful recommendations.

Comment: it is really in any insert. i tried even the one i pasted here, and i gives me thar error. The purging needs to be done in SYS or can i do it myself on the schema?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: Maybe your teacher created some DDL trigger on CREATE statement that automatically creates DML trigger on your tables. And there is some bug in these automatically created triggers. Check if there are triggers on your created tables.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on 12.1.0.2.  It could be a bug in 12.1.0.1, which is a horrible version that won't be supported for long.

Comment: Here's an article which suggests another solution: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2608475?start=0&tstart=0  "When I delete all the tables under the user and re-define the user and the tables, the error disappear."  I guess you can expand tonight's lesson into How to create Users.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a good portion of my day trying to get past this error. It would randomly go away and let me run my query, but then it would start doing it again for no reason.

"ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-30667: cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column"

Apparently it is a bug with Oracle 12.1..

**I finally found the fix, which is to run this command in sqlplus: `purge recyclebin;`**

I spent so long troubleshooting because I thought it was a problem with the sql somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still relevant  - but if it is:
If you could retry your insert using a simple command line tool, like SQL Plus, e.g. I believe you will not get that error.
It seems like you use a GUI tool that has a 'free SQL' area, and you don't mark the specific text of the insert command before executing, nor separating the different commands using semi-columns, or any other editor delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can purge the recycle bin to work-around this issue temporarily.

I am looking for the exact bug from oracle support.